# SQLite query returns a Cursor that is both null and not null

Tags: android, foreign-keys, android-sqlite

I'm working on a homework to-do app, and I want to show contact information for the professor next to the homework assignment. Each assignment has a class ID value which is a foreign key to the class table, which has a foreign key to the professor table, which has the information I'm looking for. I feel like this code should work but it isn't returning any results.

Here's the query code:

> String selectQuery = "SELECT " + KEY_CLASS_PROF +" FROM " +
>   TABLE_CLASS + " , " + TABLE_ASSGN 
>                 + " WHERE " + KEY_CLASS_ID + " = " + KEY_ASSGN_CLASS
>                 + " AND "+ KEY_ASSGN_ID + " = " + assgn_id;
>
> ```
>   Log.d(LOG, selectQuery);
>
>     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
>     Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
>
>     if (c == null)
>       Log.d(LOG,"c is null! Why is c null?");
>
>   if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
>
>       Log.d(LOG,"Cursor" + c.getPosition());
>
>       thisProf = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CLASS_PROF));
>
>       Log.d(LOG,"thisProf is " + thisProf);
>
>
>     } else Log.d(LOG,"returned null!");
> ```

and the resulting log:

> 11-12 21:51:14.508: D/DatabaseHelper(622): SELECT * FROM ClassTable ,
>   AssignmentTable WHERE classid = fk_classid AND assignmentid = 2
>
> 11-12 21:51:14.508: D/DatabaseHelper(622): returned null!

So c is not null but (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) returns false. This is driving me crazy. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I figured it out, it turned out that 0 results were returned, so even though c was not null, c.moveToFirst() was false because there was no first result to move to!

Answer (score 1):

You should change the query syntax and make that the result looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM ClassTable C join AssignmentTable A ON C.classid =
A.fk_classid  WHERE assignmentid = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

An object cannot be both `null` and not `null`, that is impossible. Let's look at your logic:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null); //you initialize the query (it isn't null now)

if (c == null) //right here you are checking if it is null or not


if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {

   //right here you have checked to make sure it isn't null AND that the
   //cursor found your query

} else Log.d(LOG,"returned null!");
   //this executes if either c == null or c cannot move to the first item (which
   //means that your query was either wrong, or turned up no results. if c was
   //actually null, your check at the top would evaluate true.
```

You're just simply misunderstanding what `c.moveToFirst()` means (that it found what you queried). A cursor can be not null and can still have found nothing, it is only null when you never initialized it. Since your middle if statement never executes and neither does your first, you know that c is not null, but your query turned up empty and c could not move to first because there was nowhere for it to go (since your query turned up empty).

I hope that clarified a little of what your seeing. Either the data you are querying just isn't there, or you are querying incorrectly, which the other answer that was posted should help you to resolve.

Comment: Thank you for the response. There's some code that I didn't include here that showed that c.moveToFirst moved the cursor from -1 to 0. I think my mistake was assuming that 0 was the index of the first result and that moveToFirst would return true (also that there would be results - I need to check the code where items were added in the first place) when the cursor is at 0. Based on that assumption, it seemed that c == null and c != null were both returning false, which is of course impossible.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think the cursor might systematically go through the data and look for your query, so the cursor would stop at the end of your data or when it found the item.